# Springboot fullstack web Developer

Tags: spring-boot

After 2 years of working  on java, spring framework and springboot, now I am trying to  make my first website. It is just a 3 pages website. I use html, css and bootstrap on the frontend and springboot for backend. I have  3 questions:

1. for backend do I need a "service" class and "service" interface? on the top of "controler" and "main" classes?
2. where do I put the photos? I mean some people says put them in the database table, some other says DB becomes heavy when you want to load it.
3. I would like to use this website as my work sample, how can I host it for free in the cloud, I think I need to host my website in the cloud, correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It depends on your needs. If the controllers' function is to return the frontend layer, then no. Generally, services are the spring way to connect the business logic layer with database layer. Which brings us to
2. the necessity, or its lack, of implementing a database at all. I'd say that if you have just a bunch of static images, feel free to place them somewhere in resources and don't bother with implementing a database layer at all. But if you, on the other hand, need to store an extensive amount of files and, more importantly, need to add and remove them dynamically, database is the way to go.
3. As for hosting: I have little experience with devops, but I'd just throw it out there, that AWS has its free-tier, lasting 12 months.